Book where a set of twins (boy and girl) develop powers and learn that their dad and his twin sister also have powers
I think they moved into a new house or something, and slowly realized that they had powers of light and shadow. They find out that their father and his twin sister have these abilities too.
I don't remember much, but I also remember them being attacked by large flies with milky eyes, I think.
Read in around 2010.

In roughly which year did you read this and when do you think it might've been published? Also, do you recall anything about the cover?
